# Having a Promising Assistant Professor vs Well- Known Full Professor as a PI

Tags: career-path, tenure-track, early-career, stem, chemistry

If one's ultimate goal is to obtain tenure (as a professor of chemistry or some other STEM field, for example), is it **honestly** better to have a more well-known professor as a PI versus an assistant professor (assuming both have equally good research and are in top-tier institutions)?

Comment: It depends far more on the individual in question than on their career situation. That said, there are tradeoffs to look out for. Other questions address these.

Comment: One problem with assistant professors is that their first priority is in getting tenure. You are not their first priority. Be aware.

Comment: @Buffy Agree it's important to be aware of tenure clocks, but it does vary by field a bit in terms of how much "things that get PI tenure" overlap or don't with "things that are good for a PhD student". Also depends on where they are in their clock.